# Connecting to WiFi dhcp device with no internet and switching to mobile data app crashes

Tags: java, android, mobile, jquery-mobile, wifi

Overview and Question

Connecting to the WiFi device with no internet and  switching to mobile data with the WiFi device still connected app does not see SSID

The WiFi device broadcast an SSID and issue an IP to the android phone. The WiFi device does not have Internet but is assign an IP. I use the mobile data for Internet. When I connect to the WiFi device with no internet and it switches to mobile data automatically when Internet is unavailable via WiFi. I load the app and it crashes. When I disable the mobile data I can load the app with no issues.Does the issues have to do with getAllNetworkInfo being deprecated? The error I am getting when I load it app is from my MainActivity.java(please_connect_to_cam_wifi).

What seems to be happening is when the mobile is enable is looses the CurrentAPSSID() and when app is loaded and looks for wifiInfo.getSSID(). I have tried add the getActiveNetworkInfo().

The globalVariables.getCurrentAPSSID() is in four of my Activities. Shouldn't the GlobalVariables.java file be modified?

The issue is not the mobile and the internet working it is passing a wifiInfo.getSSID() so that the onResume see it after the mobile is enables. Can anyone assist with the issue. Thankyou

****************************MainActivity**********************************

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "+ onResume +");

    if (!globalVariables.getCurrentAPSSID().equals(MyConfig.SPACE)) {

        startProgress(getResources().getString(R.string.progress_message_check));
        setupModel.setWifiCountDown(0);
        handlerCheckSmpDevice.postDelayed(runnableCheckSmpDevice, 10000);
    }else {
        if (MyConfig.NEW_TEST_WIFI) {
            startProgress(getResources().getString(R.string.progress_message_scan));
            globalVariables.scanWifi();
            handlerScanWifi.postDelayed(runnableScanWifi, 5000);
        }else {
            toSomethingErrorViewWithMessage(mContext,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.msg_please_connect_to_cam_wifi));
        }
    }

    isOff = false;
}
```

---

The code below is in my GlobalVariables.java.  The code below

*****************************GlobalVariables.java*************************
    /**
     * Get current connect AP ssid
     * @return String of AP ssid
     */
    public String getCurrentAPSSID() {

```
    String result = "";
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null) {

        String ssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
        if (ssid != null) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            Log.d(TAG, "networkInfo: "+networkInfo);
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                result = wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "");
            }
        }

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "wifiInfo.getSSID(): "+result);
    if (!result.equals("")) {
        tempSsid = result;
    }
    return result;
```

************************* getActiveNetworkInfo*******************************

```
getActiveNetworkInfo();

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
    }
```

Comment: Need to find out when any wifi state change then do I need to re-initialize WifiInfo i.e wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); There is a wifi state change when the mobile becomes the internet default route. How do I re-initialize when this change talks place?  The device shows that it is still connected to the SSID, The device still has an IP. I need to know how to tell WifiInfo that the device is still connected and active. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I have modified protected void onResume() { code. It seems to re-initialize WiFi state change base on the postDelayed. It now can keep both the mobile data and the WiFi enable with the mobile route. Thank you.